# append table to another div | JS jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/txcornbL/3/)

I have **2 div** in **HTML**

The *first div* for the **folder column**.

```
<div class="columnFolder-container"></div>
```

The *second div* for the **column table**. with class `._zTable`

```
<div class = "_zTable"> </ div>
```

Then in javascript, I have 1 variable (`var div =`)
which includes 1 div (`class="folder"`)  inside the div contains the table with `id="exTable"`.

I want the table to be moved into `._zTable` and not in the div class `.folder`.

Because I want the div `.folder`  in the **column folder**.

```
    var div = '<div class="folder"><span class="fname">Folder : '+name+'</span' +
              '<table id="exTable' + currentFolderIndex + '" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">' +
             '<thead>' +
                '<tr>' +
                  '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);"><input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>' +
                  '<th>Name</th>' +
                  '<th>Type</th>' +
                  '<th>Size</th>' +
                  '<th>Date Created</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
            '</thead>' +
            '</table>' +
            '</div>';
```

Comment: Please explain your problem properly.. what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I have added a fiddle to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split your variable into two.

I notice your table is inside your .folder div. I presume that shouldn't be the case.

The variables are then:

```
var div = '<div class="folder"><span class="fname">Folder : '+name+'</span></div>'
var table = '<table id="exTable' + currentFolderIndex + '" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">' +
         '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
              '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);"><input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>' +
              '<th>Name</th>' +
              '<th>Type</th>' +
              '<th>Size</th>' +
              '<th>Date Created</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '</table>';
```

Then the code to put these in the right divs is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("columnFolder-container")[0].innerHTML=div;
document.getElementsByClassName("_zTable")[0].innerHTML=table;
```

or with jquery:

```
$('.columnFolder-container').first().html(div);
$('._zTable').first().html(table);
```

Comment: Can it be like this?

$('._zTable').append(table);
$("#folder" + currentFolderIndex).DataTable({});

Comment: It could. It just depends what behaviour you want when it is clicked the second time. With .html we would replace the table every time and with .append we would add more tables. One thing to watch out for is that if you append like that then your headers will list below each other then your tables like this:

Header 1
Header 2
Table1
Table2

Comment: it's work.
I answered it myself, Lol.
but thanks for suggesting two variables.

Comment: If you want to [wrap in `div._ztable`](https://jsfiddle.net/d4m3rwx7/1/)

Comment: can you explain what the 'wrap' is for?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery :

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#exTable').appendTo('.columnFolder-container');
});`
```

Comment: .columnFolder-container is for Folder Column, not Table.

Comment: $('#exTable').appendTo('._zTable');

Comment: Sorry, This question has been answered